# Make TextField Double optional for CoreData

Tags: swiftui, core-data

My app has an option to turn off some variables from CoreData and hide them from the user if they check that option. However, im running into an issue then when saving data to CoreData where the app crashes because there is **no value put in for those entries**. The issues are from my Double variables which are inserted via Textfield. All Strings and Ints I have working correctly. Obviously my Textfields all take in a String and in my function to save the data into CoreData it converts the string to a double. But it won't let me put ?? 0 next to the doubles like it does with INT. NOTE: All variables are optional in the entity.

Here is my function for saving to CoreData which works like a charm:

```
private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            let maskTypeString = String("\(maskSelect)")
            let sleepPositionString = String("\(sleepSelect)")
            let minPressureInt = Int16("\(minPressureString)")
            let maxPressureInt = Int16("\(maxPressureString)")
            let tubeTempInt = Int16("\(tubeTempString)")
            
            guard let hoursSleptDouble = Double(hoursSleptString)  else {
                print("hours slept reading is invalid")
                return
            }
            guard let ahiDouble = Double(ahiString) else {
                print("ahi reading is invalid")
                return
            }
            guard let leaksDouble = Double(leaksReadingString) else {
                print("leaks reading is invalid")
                return
            }
            guard let hoursMaskDouble = Double(hoursWithMaskString) else {
                print("hours with mask reading is invalid")
                return
            }
            
            newItem.id = UUID()
            newItem.usedCPAP = usedCPAPToggle
            newItem.ahiReading = ahiDouble
            newItem.hoursSlept = hoursSleptDouble
            newItem.feelingGood = feelingToggle
            newItem.todaysDate = todaysDateInput
            newItem.leaksReading = leaksDouble
            newItem.humiditySetting = humiditySettingString
            newItem.eprSetting = eprSettingString
            newItem.sleepPosition = sleepPositionString
            newItem.maskType = maskTypeString
            newItem.headacheToggle = headacheToggle
            newItem.hoursWithMask = hoursMaskDouble
            newItem.alcoholDrinks = alcoholDrinksToggle
            newItem.workoutFactor = workoutToggle
            newItem.caffeineDrinks = caffeineDrinksToggle
            newItem.sleepNotes = sleepNotes
            newItem.minPressure = minPressureInt ?? 0
            newItem.maxPressure = maxPressureInt ?? 0
            newItem.ateLate = ateLateToggle
            newItem.drugsTaken = drugsTakenToggle
            newItem.eprRamp = eprRampToggle
            newItem.tubeTemp = tubeTempInt ?? 0
            newItem.napTaken = napTakenToggle

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
                dismiss()
                print("Success")
            } catch {
                print("CoreData save fail!!!")
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"But it won't let me..."* What happens when you try?

Comment: Post the code that fails and include more info about the crash, what error do you get?

Comment: The whole app just crashes on my actual phone. On Xcode simulator the console throws the 'ahi reading is invalid' statements and refuses to submit anything, staying on that same view.  I've narrowed it down to it happening only on the Double variables that are obtained from textfields. I don't see why it would crash the app on the actual phone.

Comment: This is very vague and your handling of optional properties are unclear. Maybe you have two separate issues here, the unknown crash and the handling of optional properties

Comment: Regarding the “ahi reading”, you are aware that calling `return` when the conversion to double fails means the function is terminated and nothing gets saved?

Comment: That is the point of the function because I want to make those fields optional if they turn the CPAP fields off in settings. Or are you saying by having those functions like that, if there isn't anything in there, its crashing the app because it has nothing to save at all rather than a 0? The console never prints the success message or the CoreData failed message so its not even getting to that point when those fields are empty. It just states ahiReading is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joakim Danielson above who solved this for me. I removed the guard/else statements and made them plain constants converting the strings to Doubles. And then when assigning the values to CoreData, used the ?? 0 which it now allowed.

```
let hoursSleptDouble = Double(hoursSleptString)
let ahiDouble = Double(ahiString)
let leaksDouble = Double(leaksReadingString)
let hoursMaskDouble = Double(hoursWithMaskString)

newItem.ahiReading = ahiDouble ?? 0
newItem.hoursSlept = hoursSleptDouble ?? 0
newItem.leaksReading = leaksDouble ?? 0
newItem.hoursWithMask = hoursMaskDouble ?? 0
```